Did Trump stage his own assassination attempt?
There have been a lot of theories around the semi-recent Trump assassination attempt, both on the left and the right.   One of these theories I have been hearing directly is that Trump staged his own assassination.   Basically, him or someone close to him planned a fake assassination attempt in order to make Trump into a would-be martyr for his cause.
I believe this theory is circulating heavily on Twitter and Tiktok at the time of this writing.
So the reasons why they believe the event was staged:

Trump's ear was fully healed only a few months later and ears' are slow healing
Trump was not hit directly by a bullet despite the shooter having a clear shot on him
How could the Secret Service be so foolish and lax to let the shooter slowly get into position in the open and start shooting?
The secret service is supposed to keep the protectee down, yet he was only slowly pulled down and allowed to give a fist pump later.
The shooter had pipe bombs despite lacking the expertise to build them

I believe there are more justifications that people are considering, but these are the ones I see and hear.
Was the Trump assassination attempt staged by Trump?

What would you consider to be a good answer? I mean, Trump has not been charged, let alone convicted, of any crimes related to the shooting, so the official position is that he is innocent. Anything else is going to be largely speculation and anomaly hunting.

Do you have evidence that Trump's ear healed very fast?

"you can't be skeptical of a conspiracy theory unless someone's been charged with a crime related to it" is a terrible argument. It's notable, there's plenty of evidence around it because it was a public event, and it's no longer really an ongoing current event. Seems like a perfectly good question to me.

You should add quotes from your links for all the things you say they're claiming. Context is important, and links can rot.

This is strictly off-topic as subject of an ongoing investigation. The answers already say that as well.

@Nij Where do we say subjects of an ongoing investigation are off topic?

It's been policy for over a decade. It's exactly one of the flag/close reasons. "Questions about unresolved current events and issues currently under investigation by a court of law, government, or other similar investigative body are off-topic because there is insufficient data for a meaningful answer. For more information, see Handling current news questions." @Schwern

@Nij I don't consider an answer buried in meta to be strictly anything. There's nothing in the help center about it. Besides, it would disqualify half the Trump questions. :)

@CJR: You are misrepresenting me. Of course we should be skeptical of such claims. The question is what would make a satisfactory answer on Skeptics.SE, where we eschew opinions and personal evaluations of probabilities for references to empirical data. I effectively asked what sort of evidence (in each direction) that would be accepted here would be convincing to the OP, because I am not seeing how an answer could be any good. We already have an unreferenced answer of someone's personal opinion.

@Schwern: We must have closed dozens of questions for this reason by now. We can only report the evidence that other scientists/journalists/law-enforcement/etc have uncovered. If the world's journalists are trying to seek answers to a big news event, so they can report it on the front page of the newspapers, we can't hope to beat them to it.

If a direct link from an explicit close menu option counts as "buried", nothing on meta is findable at all. Doesn't change what the policy is, or that you've been around long enough to see it in action. The fact that other questions are also possibly off-topic and open does not make this one not off-topic or justify not closing it.

@Oddthinking - Its been awhile, I don't think there will be much more reporting on it.  It doesn't seem likely much more of note will come out about the incident.

@MarkRogers: Again, what would a good answer look like. You know the official position. You know the conspiracy theories. What is left to add?

@Oddthinking - Anything that addresses some of the sub-claims I posted or makes an argument more generally.

@MarkRogers: Unfortunately, debunking one or two of the listed anomalies doesn't address the overall claim. If you want to pick one of the anomalies, we can address that as a single question. e.g. "Did Trump's ear heal impossibly fast?" (with a direct quote making that claim). However, that won't tell us whether there was a conspiracy. At the moment, there could be 5 different perfect answers, addressing one each of the 5 different claims you listed, and there would be no way to accept them all, and still no way of answering the title question.

There is an ongoing FBI investigation into the shooting
If the shooting was faked, the FBI will begin to find evidence for it. Trump's team is just not that good at hiding things. I'm not going to entertain the idea that the FBI investigators are in on it, too.
Pipe bombs are easy

The shooter had pipe bombs despite lacking the expertise to build them

A pipe bomb is one of the simplest bombs and can be made with things from the hardware store. Plans are easy to find on the internet. The shooter was buying up guns and explosive parts for a year before the assassination.

The gunman who tried to assassinate Donald Trump began making dozens of gun-related purchases and stocking up on bomb-making materials more than a year ago, FBI officials said Monday, the strongest indication yet that he had been planning an attack well before he opened fire on the former president.
Thomas Matthew Crooks made 25 different gun-related buys online between spring 2023 and the first half of this year, and bought material used in explosives six times, officials said, offering new glimpses into their far-ranging investigation into the July 13 shooting at a campaign rally in western Pennsylvania.
FBI officials said Crooks, 20 years old, searched online for information about power plants, mass-shooting events, improvised explosive devices and the May assassination attempt on Slovakia’s prime minister, said Kevin Rojek, the FBI special agent in charge in Pittsburgh.

Trump Shooter Began Buying Guns, Bomb Materials More Than a Year Ago, FBI Says via WSJ.
The shooter was inexperienced and flustered

Trump was not hit directly by a bullet despite the shooter having a clear shot on him

The same person the conspiracy says is too incompetent to make a pipe bomb is also such an expert shot they couldn't have missed?
The shot was 120 meters and the shooter was young and inexperienced. Firing on a range is not the same as firing in the open at a person. Making a head shot at 120 meters, even with a [assumed to be zeroed] scope, requires breath control and experience with the weapon.
Less than a minute before he opened fire the shooter was confronted by police.

Sheriff Slupe said this officer was hoisted by another officer to the roof of a building where the shooter had taken a position.
The shooter, Crooks, focused his rifle on the officer who let go and fell off the roof. Then, the 20-year-old began firing into the crowd.

This would throw off any shooter's cool, especially an inexperienced, young, mentally unstable shooter.
We know very little about Trump's ear

Trump's ear was fully healed only a few months later and ears' are slow healing

Talk about a tempest in a teapot, we're down to a miraculously healing ear?
No clear photo of the wound has been revealed, nor have medical records been released.

Trump's campaign has neither disclosed his medical records from the initial hospital treatment nor allowed the attending physicians to be questioned.

Both Trump and his former White House physician Ronny Jackson have given details about the wound. Ronny Jackson claimed the bullet "produced a 2 cm wide wound that extended down to the cartilaginous surface of the ear". Both have embellished information about Trump's health to Trump's advantage in the past.
More plausible is that Trump, Ronny Jackson, and the Trump campaign are making the wound sound more grisly than it was, and using this as an opportunity to create a story of miraculous healing to further Trump's messiah narrative.

“It was God alone who prevented the unthinkable from happening,” Trump wrote in a Truth Social post in the immediate aftermath of the shooting. “We will FEAR NOT, but instead remain resilient in our Faith and Defiant in the face of Wickedness.”
...
It’s a conviction that will certainly reinforce the messianic imagery of Trump long promoted by his most ardent supporters and the evangelical communities that have stood by him for years. Indeed, outside the venue Saturday, as rallygoers were evacuated, they passed a truck emblazoned with images of Trump seated in front of Jesus, whose hands rested on the former president’s shoulders.

An unusually reflective Trump suggests divine intervention in aftermath of rally shooting

None of those arguments seem particularly convincing:

The ear: is there evidence that it's healed very fast? This picture turned out to be old.

Before opening fire the shooter had just pointed his weapon at a policeman climbing on to the roof. Then he had to quickly re-acquire Trump and start firing before he was shot himself. According to the news report the USSS opened fire about 6 seconds after the shooter, but the shooter himself didn't know how long he had. Lack of accuracy is unsurprising.

The laxity of the USSS is surprising, but not extraordinary. Big organisations get like that. The mix of USSS and state and local police with separate hierarchies and no unified communication structure on the day also contributed.

But they have state and local law enforcement that were responsible for those other perimeters. They should have had other Secret Service personnel coding, coordinating that out there and clearly they didn't. [ibid]


The USSS might want to keep the target down, but they also want to walk him off as fast as possible. That meant standing him up. The fist-pump only took a second, and the USSS weren't going to put him in a come-along hold and frog-march him off.

Pipe bomb recipes are widely available over the Internet. If you follow a recipe then at the end you will have a pipe bomb no matter how inexpert you are. Whether its a viable device is another matter, but inexperienced amateurs have produced viable devices in the past.


Against this theory is the list of things required for this to be a staged attempt:

The shooter has to have real bullets because those bullets must be found (and in this case a bystander was killed, so we know these weren't blanks). So at the very least there is a serious risk to the target, even if the shooter is aiming to miss.

Between the USSS and the police there were dozens of security people. You couldn't get all of these people on-board with a secret criminal plot:

There is no common reporting structure so you can't simply suborn their boss.

None of them report to Trump, so he can't just give them orders.

Having such a thing on their watch is going to be a black mark on their careers.

Many of these people take their oaths of service very seriously. Telling who can be suborned ahead of time is difficult and unreliable, and you can't pick and choose without going even higher in the organisation to someone who can fix the duty roster.



On the other hand, if the USSS and police aren't in on the plot, the shooter has to be willing to die for a publicity stunt. Any volunteers?



I believe that the secret service prefers USSS and not SS for... a good reason

Please provide some references to support your claims.
